# How do I configure a USB ethernet adapter under CentOS 5.3?

Tags: centos5, ethernet, linux-networking, drivers

I've got a server running CentOS 5.3 (Final; kernel version 2.6.18) which I need to add a 2nd NIC to, initially temporarily, but eventually permanently. I'm not familiar with installing drivers under Linux and have only used `system-config-network-tui` and editing config files (we have no version of X installed) to configure the built-in ethernet adapter.

I found a few notes [stating that the Apple USB Ethernet adapter works well under Linux](http://free-electrons.com/blog/usbeth/). We're an Apple shop, so we have plenty and that'll do for the short term while we track down a better PCI-X ethernet adapter for this server. So, I downloaded & installed (`make` and `make install`) the [appropriate version of the recommended AX88178 driver (Linux 2.6.38; for "Android 1.x/2.x/3.0, Linux kernel 2.6.14 and later")](http://www.asix.com.tw/download.php?sub=searchresult&PItemID=84&download=driver). After plugging in the Apple USB Ethernet adapter, it does show in the results of `lsusb`, but does not show in the options when I run `system-config-network-tui`.

The .ko file that was compiled & installed was "asix.ko" and if I run `lsmod | grep asix`, I get the following:

```
asix                   82176  0 
mii                    38849  1 asix
```

So, does that the kernel module is correctly installed & loaded? Do I need to alias "eth2" ("eth0" is the built-in ethernet and "eth1" is listed in `system-config-network-tui` as "skge", but is definitely not what I just plugged in) to "asix" in `/etc/modules.conf` as [noted here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-broadcom-ethernet-card-driver-installation/)? What other steps might I be missing?

Of note: I do now see a "dev23116" network interface when I run `ifconfig -a` that wasn't there before I installed the drivers. Is *that* the USB ethernet adapter? If so, do I alias that or use that as the interface's device in `system-config-network-tui`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the 'devXXXXX' interface was generated whenever I plugged in the Apple USB Ethernet adapter (and went away when unplugged), but it changed, so I don't expect it to have the same device name after a reboot. (Not to mention I couldn't get an IP to stick to it when configuring using `system-config-network-tui`.)

When plugging the Apple USB Ethernet adapter in, I got the following in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Sep 21 13:40:15 hostname kernel: usb 1-6: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 6
Sep 21 13:40:15 hostname kernel: usb 1-6: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Sep 21 13:40:15 hostname kernel: ASIX USB Ethernet Adapter:v4.1.0 17:04:38 Sep 20 2011
Sep 21 13:40:15 hostname kernel:     http://www.asix.com.tw
Sep 21 13:40:15 hostname kernel: eth%d: status ep1in, 8 bytes period 11
Sep 21 13:40:15 hostname kernel: eth1: register 'asix' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-6, ASIX AX88772A USB 2.0 Ethernet, ffff8100769819a8M
```

I did find a line reading `alias eth1 skge` in `/etc/modprobe.conf` (for that odd eth1 interface that is not anything and never shows up as connected) and commented it out (esp. since `/var/logs/messages` show the log registering asix as eth1). After doing so, giving eth1 a static IP using `system-config-network-tui`, and disconnected & reconnecting the Apple USB Ethernet adapter, it now always shows up as eth1 and with the correct ethernet address. I can also ping hosts on that subnet, so this is working.

The main issue appears to have been the conflict between the hard-coded alias and the asix module trying to register as the same name.

**One additional note:** It seems to change the default route to the Apple USB Ethernet adapter whenever it's plugged in, so you have to be sure to check that & adjust, if necessary.